# Overloading the () operator for an enum in a class - C++

Tags: c++, enums

I came across the following piece of code :-

```
class MyClass{

public:

    enum ITEMS {

        ZERO = 0,
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE

    };

    enum ITEMS item;
    MyClass():item(THREE){}
    MyClass(ITEMS item):item(item){};
    operator ITEMS () {
        return item;
    }

};
```

I am unable to figure out what the operator() overloading on the enum ITEMS does . How would that be used in the context of objects of type MyClass ? Suppose we have an object :-

```
MyClass obj1;
```

Can we do `obj1.VALUES()` ? I am getting compilation errors if I try that.

Comment: `operator()` is something else.

Comment: What actually makes you think you can do `obj1.VALUES()` and what should that be?

Answer (score 3):

`operator ITEMS (){...}` is a **cast** overload for target type `ITEMS`. When you cast an instance of `MyClass` to type `MyClass::ITEMS`, class member `item` gets returned.

Answer (score 2):

It allows you do make a conversion from object of type `MyClass` to variable of type `ITEMS`, example:

```
MyClass mm;
MyClass::ITEMS it = mm;
```